# Error: could not find function "workspace"

Tags: r, azure, powerbi

I am trying to access an Azure ML Workspace from RStudio using the script:

```
install.packages("AzureML")
ws <- workspace(
id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
auth = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
)
```

and get the error **could not find function "workspace"**
The workspace id and primary authorisation token are 100% correct.
I am very new to R and presume I am making a schoolboy error.
Any help gratefully appreciated ?
Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureML/vignettes/getting_started.html suggests the following:

```
library(AzureML)
ws <- workspace(
  id = "your workspace ID",
  auth = "your authorization token"
)
```

Your code is missing the `library(AzureML)` part.

Documentation of `library`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/library

After calling that, the `workspace` function should be available.